# node.js global variables use?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
global.test = "test";
console.log(global.test); //test
```

but I want to do this

```
console.log(test); //test
```

not use

```
var test = global.test;
```

How can I do it? I want any module in my project not need to assign all global scope variable in ecah scope to use these global node.js global variables.

Comment: `global.foo = 'bar'; console.log(foo); // bar`

The code above works. What's the problem?

Comment: Also, this is almost always a bad idea, why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Properties you add to the global object become global variables, so:

```
global.test = "foo";
console.log(test); // "foo"
```

But using global variables is almost always a bad idea. Instead, put the thing you want to share in a module, and load that module into other modules that need to use it:

`test.js`:

```
exports.test = "foo";
```

Anything that needs to use it:

```
var test = require("./test.js").test;
console.log(test);
```